# how to join two List of different signature type with a common property using Java stream()?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```java
class ScannedCoupon{
    Long id;
    String scannedcode;
}
        
class WinnerCoupon{
    Long id;
    String winnercode;
    boolean won;
}
    
List<ScannedCoupon> scannedCouponList;
List<WinnerCoupon> winnerCouponList;
```

Here are my cases:

I do have two lists `scannedCouponList` with 30 items and `winnerCouponList` with 200. one them is code scanned by users and other is the list of winner. I want to update `winnerCouponList` if any of the  `ScannedCoupon`'s `scannedcode` is inside `winnerCouponList`.

is there any way to update the `won` property to `true` from `winnerCouponList` if any of the `winnercode == scannedcode` from `scannedCouponList` using java `stream()` ?

I do not want to use loops over and over again for 200 `WinnerCoupon` if any one of them is in `scannedCouponList` or not.

Comment: I think that from the class design perspective the second class isn't required. You can achieve the same thing with **two boolean flags** (like is *isWinningCoupon* in addition to the existing one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can collect the scanned codes to a `Set`.

```java
Set<String> scannedCodes = scannedCouponList.stream()
                                            .map(ScannedCoupon::getScannedCode)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The above set helps to avoid looping the scanned list for each winner coupon as `Set.contains` has `O(1)` time complexity.
Now, stream the winner coupon list and check if the code is available in `scannedCodes`:

```java
winnerCouponList.stream()
                .filter(coupon -> scannedCodes.contains(coupon.getWinnerCode()))
                .forEach(coupon -> coupon.setWon(true));
```

Since the winner list size is much more than your scanned list, this would have approximately `O(n)` time complexity (considering the size of scanned list is very small compared to winner list) where `n` is size of winner list.

Comment: i think this one filters out my main `winnerCouponList`  if any of them is matched with `scannedCouponList`. for example if there is no match between `winnerCouponList` and `scannedCouponList`  it would return null or empty List right?.  i want to update `winnerCouponList` with `setWon(true)` if matched or `setWon(false)` if no match.  `winnerCouponList`  items should remain same with updated property. please correct me if I got you wrong.

Comment: @smnadim21 `forEach` does not return anything. It just applies the operation on every element in the list. So `winnerCouponList` remains the same, except that the matching elements would have `won = true`

Comment: i have  got a shorter result than yours we may not need the `filter()` option as we can do just this:  `winnerCouponList.stream().forEach(coupon -> coupon.setWon(scannedCodes.contains(coupon.getWinnerCode())));`

Comment: @smnadim21 Yes that could be used as well. Or just simply `list.forEach` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

We loop around on **winnerCouponList** and at the same time for each **winnerCoupon** we check in **scannedCoupon** list have `scannedCode == winnerCode`.
If yes, then we update the `winnerCoupon.won = true`. If no, we will continue in our loop until we found `scannedCode == winnerCode` or we reach the end of **scannedCouponList**

```
winnerCouponList.stream()
   .forEach(winnerCoupon -> {
       scannedCouponList.stream()
       .filter(scannedCoupon -> {
           return scannedCoupon.scannedcode.equals(winnerCoupon.winnercode);
       })
       .limit(1)
       .forEach(scannedCoupon -> winnerCoupon.won = true);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
winnerCouponList.stream()
    .filter(w -> scannedCouponList.stream()
    .anyMatch(s -> s.scannedcode.equals(w.winnercode)))
    .forEach(w -> w.setWon(true));
```